# Gradle analogue for maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-assembly-plugin

I use assembly maven plugin in my project, to deliver jars, procrun executables and some scripts from `src/main/scripts/` folder in single zip-file. How can I do it with gradle?
I've saw gradle delivery and application plugins but I couldn't configure them in right way.

Comment: What exactly would You like to do? Can You provide any sample input and expected output?

Comment: This doesn't tell much.

Comment: @Opal I have some files in `src/main/scripts/` dir. There are *.exe, *.sh, *.bat files. Maven process them converts variables like ${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}, and then create archive with `bin/,lib/,conf/` folders. `bin/` contains scripts and exe files with 0744 permissions, `lib/` contains jars of my project and it's dependencies, `conf/` contains files from `src/main/resources/`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Maven assembly can easily be replaced Gradle's [distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html). The configuration consists of two parts.

### Configuring the distribution

The first part of the configuration is the declaration of the contents of the distribution:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
  main {
   baseName = project.name
    contents {
      into('lib/') {  // Copy the following jars to the lib/ directory in the distribution archive
        from jar
        from configurations.runtimeClasspath
        dirMode = 0755
        fileMode = 0644
      }
      from('src/main/dist') {  // Contents of this directory are copied by default
        dirMode = 0755
        fileMode = 0644
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This `contents` section is just an example. Depending on your project you probably want to do different things here. A description of the configuration options can be found in the Javadocs of the [AbstractCopyTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html) and the interfaces it implements.

Files in *src/main/dist* are automatically added to the distribution. Even if there is no correspondent `from` statement in the publication. The second path element must match the name of the distribution (*main* in my example). I listed the directory in my example because I need to set the `fileMode` and `dirMode` properties on the copied files.

#### Filtering files

Filtering files is also possible using one of the [filter()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ContentFilterable.html#filter(java.util.Map,%20java.lang.Class)) methods defined in the `AbstractCopyTask`.

The example below uses the `ReplaceTokens` filter. It replaces ant-style place holders formatted like this: `@placeholder@`.

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

contents {  // contents section in distribution
  from('src/main/scripts') {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [placeholder: 'replacement-string' ])
    filteringCharset = 'UTF-8'
  }
}
```

This will replace the string `@placeholder@` in all files copied from the *src/main/scripts* directory with "replacement-string" in the distribution archive.

The Javadocs for [ContentFilterable](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/ContentFilterable.html) describe some alternative ways to filter files.

### Configuring the file archives

The second part of the configuration allows to manage file format specific features of the generated archive files. These settings are optional and only required if you are not happy with the format of the standard archives.

By default Gradle does not compress the tar archive it produces. The example below configures the `distTar` task to compress the tar-file using gzip. As files are usually distributed as .tar.gz files and not just as tar files, it is a good idea to add this to the build:

```
distTar {
  compression = Compression.GZIP
  extension = 'tar.gz'
  classifier = 'dist'  // Appends a suffix to the file name
}
```

See the [Tar task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Tar.html) for a description of all configuration options.

The zip archive can be configured in the same way as the tar archive. This example simply adds a classifier string to the end of the file name:

```
distZip {
  classifier = 'dist'
}
```

See the [Tar task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html) for a description of other configuration options.

### Build the distribution archives

The distribution archives are created as part of the `assemble` task. Running `gradle build` or `gradle assemble` will produce them.

Comment: @glebiuskv I noticed you had the requirement to filter files in your distribution. I have added a section on this to my answer. It would helpful if you could move this requirement from the comment to your question i think.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Copy and Zip tasks, in my experience they can do more than 
assembly plugin with less ceremony

https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html
https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Zip.html